# Retrieve right yr from in sql query

Tags: mysql

I'm just starting out with mySql and have a quick question as to why my query related to question 8 on this website: http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_from_Nobel_Tutorial doesn't work.

I tried to do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT yr FROM
(SELECT * FROM nobel WHERE NOT subject = 'Chemistry') AS x
WHERE subject = 'Physics'
```

An explanation would be superb, i already found ways queries that work, but i would like to see where my logic failed me.

Comment: Isn't working means? Also please provide example data and expected output. Put all info needed in the question.

Comment: @juergend, all the info needed **is** in the question

Comment: @svz: No, questions should be self containing and independent on external links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The catch is in the subquery: `SELECT * FROM nobel WHERE NOT subject = 'Chemistry'`. It selects all rows where subject is not Chemistry. Rows, but not years. As there are many nominations for Nobel prize each year, you will still get a list of all years in your selection.
After that you check for rows with physics, which are present almost every year and get the wrong answer.

I wonder if people here ever read questions asked..

Comment: Thanks so much, it starts to make sense now. :)

Comment: This is how i finally did it with my primitive knowledge so far. Thanks for your pointer

SELECT DISTINCT yr FROM nobel WHERE yr NOT IN
(SELECT DISTINCT yr FROM nobel WHERE subject = 'Chemistry')
AND subject = 'Physics'

Answer (score 1):

You can do a subquery with `NOT EXISTS` to ask for the Years that have a Physics prize and don't have a Chemistry prize:

```
SELECT DISTINCT yr FROM
nobel n1 WHERE subject = 'Physics'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM nobel n2
                WHERE n1.yr = n2.yr
                  AND subject = 'Chemistry')
```

EDIT:

Looking at your query, here's why it isn't working:

If you had:

```
1960    Chemistry   Willard F. Libby
1960    Physics     Saint-John Perse
1961    Chemistry   Sir Frank Macfarlane Burnet
1961    Physics     Peter Medawar
```

Your subquery would return:

```
1960    Physics     Saint-John Perse
1961    Physics     Peter Medawar
```

Then with your outer query you want the ones that have subject Physics, which would give you all the results.

In order for it to work you have to relate the year where Physics has won and Chemistry wasn't awarded.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be

```
select yr
from nobel
group by yr
having sum(subject = 'Chemistry') = 0 
and sum(subject = 'Physics') >= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try  this:

```
SELECT distinct yr FROM
nobel x1 WHERE subject = 'Physics'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM nobel x2 WHERE x1.yr = x2.yr
                      AND subject = 'Chemistry')
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_from_Nobel_Tutorial)**

Your subquery `SELECT * FROM nobel WHERE NOT subject = 'Chemistry'` will select all rows from the table where subject is not equal to `Chemistry` but you want to check there existence only. So you may replace `* with 1`.

Comment: Your advice to replace * with 1 doesn't quite make sense in OP's query.